# server-to-server REST API security

Tags: security, rest

We're building a REST API that will only be accessed from a known set of servers. My question is, if there is no access directly from any browser based clients, what security mechanisms are required.

Currently Have:

- Obviously over HTTPS
- Have HTTP auth enabled, API consumers have a Key & password

Is it neccessary to:

- Create some changing key, e.g. `md5(timestamp + token)` that is formed for the request and validated at the endpoint?
- Use OAuth (2-legged authentication)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't matter - from browser or not.

> Is it neccessary to:
>
> Create some changing key, e.g. md5(timestamp + token) that is formed
>   for the request and validated at the endpoint?
>
> Use oauth (2-legged authorization)?

**Use OAuth**, it solves both these questions. And OAuth usage is good because:

- You aren't reinventing wheel
- There are already a lot of libraries and approaches depending on technology stack

You can also use JWT token to pass some security context with custom claims from service to service.

Also as reference you can look how different providers solve the problem. For example Azure Active Directory has on behalf flow for this purpose 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Use of OAuth2/OpenID Connect is not mandatory between your services, there are other protocols and alternatives and even custom. All depends in which relationships are services and either they both are in full trust environment.

You can use anything you like but main idea not to share sensitive information between services like service account credentials or user credentials.

If REST API security is main requirement  - OAuth2/OpenID Connect is maybe the best choice, if you need just secure (in a sense of authentication) calls in full trust environment in a simplest way - Kerberos, if you need encrypted custom tunnel between them for data in transit encryption - other options like VPN. It does not make sense to implement somthing custom because if you have Service A and Service B, and would like to make sure call between them is authenticated, then to avoid coupling and sharing senstive information you will always need some central service C as Identity provider. So if you think from tis pov, OAuth2/OIDC is not overkill

Comment: OAuth seems like overkill for server to server comms, and much more expensive to implement. It's not like you need a 3rd party for identity management and authorisation. It's also unlikely in this situation you need a token based mechanism granting access to some resources but not others. SSL + password seems sufficient in the given context.

Comment: It depends. Basic idea is to exchange login-password pair to some token. It could be OAuth token or it could be session id/guid or something else. Just not to send password between servers/services

Comment: OAuth allows me to let a 3rd party verify who I am with e.g. Google. I don't see the use case for this in purely server side authentication where you control the environment... Also why would you not send a password between servers/services in the same environment?

Comment: @Bryji Why not send password? Because of security issues. It could be logged, it could be sniffed etc. It is bad sign to send password in plain text even inside your infrastructure. When you need it, at least hashed. About OAuth. Again basic idea is to issue some token and send it instead of login and password. And token can carry not only credentials, but roles, user info and id etc. If OAuth is not your use case - don't use it, use Basic authentication and then for token use Guids, Base64 string from JSON/XML or any other token format.

Comment: That's why you use SSL, obviously don't use http basic auth without.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the consumers of your API are web browsers or servers you don't control doesn't change the security picture.

If you are using HTTPs and clients already have a key/password then it isn't clear what kind of attack any other mechanism would protect against.

Any compromise on the client side will expose everything anyway.

Comment: If your API consumers have code that generates a changing hash (token), then an attacker may have the consumers user & pass to get passed HTTP authentication, but the request will still fail because they don't know how to generate the token which is validated by the endpoint, after HTTP auth, but before resources are accessed.

Comment: Obviously if the client has everything it needs, then you're screwed. The question is about preventing that. Communicating over SSL, signing requests, etc..

Comment: If you add a secondary authentication mechanism (eg. SecureID) then you are definitely increasing the security.  Adding an algorithm to generate a hash is adding another piece to the protocol that is presumably less secure than the original password (since all clients must know the algorithm).  How do you communicate this algorithm to clients?  Why not simply add a second password in that case?  My point is that it isn't fundamentally changing the security model, at best just adding defense in depth (which isn't necessarily a bad thing)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - it matters whether a user agent (such as a browser) is involved in call.

If there are only S2S calls then 1 way SSL HTTPS (for network encryption) and some kind of signature mechanism (SHA-256) should be enough for your security.

However if you return sensitive information in your api response, its always better to accept 2 way ssl HTTPS connections (in order to validate the client).

OAuth2 doesn't add any value in a server to server call (that takes place without user consent and without any user agent present).

Answer (score 0):

For authentication between servers:

### Authentication

**Known servers:**

- use **TLS** with **X.509 client certificates** (TLS with mutual authentication).
- issue the client certificates with a **common CA** (certificate authority). That way, the servers need only have the CA certificate or public key in the truststore, and new client certificates for additional clients/servers can be issued without having to update the truststores.

**Open set of servers:**

- use **API keys**, issued by a central authority. The servers need to validate these keys on each request (and may cache the hashes of the keys along with the validation result for some short time).

### Identity propagation

- if the requests are executed in the context of a **non-technical user**, use **JWT** (or SAML) for **identity propagation of the user principal and claims** (authorize at security proxy/WAF/IAM, and issue JWT signed by authentication server).
- otherwise the user principal refers to the **technical user** and can can be extracted from the client certificate (X.509 DName) or be returned with a successful authentication response (API key case).